# Trimming URL with XSL

Tags: xslt

I have some XSL on a page with a URL of:

```
site.domain.com/dir/dir/dir/dir
```

The same XSL also appears on a page with URL of:

```
site.domain.com/dir/dir/dir
```

I need links from these two pages to point to:

```
site.domain.com/dir/dir/site
```

So on both pages I need to get: `site.domain.com/dir/dir` as part of the HREF attribute.

Can anyone think how I might do this in XSL?

Comment: Are you talking about pseudo `href` attribute in Processing Instructions (PI)? Are you asking about stylesheet document URI? Then, starting `/` in a relative URI means "domains root", so `/dir/dir` will be resolved to `domain.com/dir/dir` from any subfolder.

Answer (score 1):

Step-by-step string processing by recursion:

```
<xsl:template name="trim-url">
  <xsl:param name="url" select="''" />
  <xsl:param name="lvl" select="0" />

  <xsl:if test="$lvl &gt; 0">
    <xsl:variable name="tmp" select="concat($url, '/')" />

    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($tmp, '/')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="'/'" />

    <xsl:call-template name="trim-url">
      <xsl:with-param name="url" select="substring-after($tmp, '/')" />
      <xsl:with-param name="lvl" select="$lvl - 1" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

called as follows:

```
<xsl:variable name="trimmed-url">
  <xsl:call-template name="trim-url">
    <xsl:with-param name="url" select="$url" />
    <xsl:with-param name="lvl" select="3" />
  </xsl:call-template>
  <xsl:value-of select="'site'" />
</xsl:variable>
```

When `$url` is `'site.domain.com/dir/dir/dir/dir'`, then `$trimmed-url` will be `'site.domain.com/dir/dir/site'`.